# Pandas df.apply with additional arguments

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to apply a function in pandas that requires me to use an additional variable to score. Example:

```
def get_score_threshold(pred_df):
    score_thresholds = {}
    score_thresholds['a_thresh'] = np.percentile(pred_df['pred'],75)
    score_thresholds['b_thresh'] = np.percentile(pred_df['pred'],50)
    score_thresholds['c_thresh'] = np.percentile(pred_df['pred'],25)
    return score_thresholds

def score_pred(pred,scores):
    if pred >= scores['a_thresh']:
        return 'A'
    elif pred >= scores['b_thresh']:
        return 'B'
    elif pred >= scores['c_thresh']:
        return 'C'
    else: return 'D'

close_preds['score'] = close_preds['pred'].apply(score_pred(scores=close_pred_thresh))
```

How do I specify that the first variable is the row being passed and the second is the additional argument I'm providing?

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) it would appear to be

```
close_preds['score'] = close_preds['pred'].apply(score_pred, args=(pred, scores))
```

I can't see what your `close_pred_thresh` is though. The `score_pred` needs two arguments.